# Error while using tidytable packge dealing with timeseries data

Tags: r, data.table, tidytable

I have a time series data with two columns `timestamps` and `value`:

```
as.data.table(structure(list(timestamp = c("2023-10-04 09:59:58", "2023-10-04 10:02:58", 
"2023-10-04 10:05:58", "2023-10-04 10:08:58", "2023-10-04 10:11:58", 
"2023-10-04 10:14:58", "2023-10-04 10:17:58"), value = c(1, 2.5, 
4, 5.5, 7, 8.5, 10)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame")))
```

Im trying to find the average value at every 15min interval

```
library(tidytable)
library(dplyr)



averaged_df <- df %>%
  group_by(interval = floor_date(timestamp, "15 minutes")) %>%
  summarise(average_value = mean(value))
```

> Error in `group_by()`: ℹ In argument: `interval = floor_date(timestamp, "15 minutes")`. Caused by error in
> `floor_date()`: ! could not find function "floor_date"

Without tidytable it works as expected but when the `tidytable` is loaded it gives the above error.

Comment: Submit a bug report to the author. `tidytable` is breaking external functions. `dtplyr` works fine, as do both `dplyr`/`data.table`-canonical code. If `tidytable` cannot accept arbitrary functions, something in its design may be at fault. In the interim, `dtplyr` works (and its goal is the same), ala `library(dtplyr); lazy_dt(df) %>% mutate(timestamp = as.POSIXct(timestamp)) %>% group_by(interval = floor_date(timestamp, "15 minutes")) %>% summarise(average_value = mean(value)) %>% collect()`

Comment: @r2evans https://github.com/markfairbanks/tidytable/issues/772

Comment: Very interesting, good find.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/markfairbanks/tidytable/issues/772

`group_by()` cannot be used to create columns instead `mutate()` should be used when `tidytable` is loaded.

*markfairbanks*